# Multiprocessing manager.list using list subclass

Tags: python, multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am trying to use my list subclass on calling manager.list. So, I can add my own methods, but it is not working. Is it possible to do this?

```
class mylist(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
                 
myinherit = mylist()
#myinherit.append(2)

import multiprocessing as mp
mpl    = mp.Manager()
llist  = mpl.list(myinherit)
llist.append(10)



    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)

RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\E0238015\Anaconda3\envs\zezo\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 193, in handle_request
    request = c.recv()
  File "C:\Users\E0238015\Anaconda3\envs\zezo\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'mylist' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register

Comment: @Monica, thank you. I checked the link, but can't apply it. Can you please help with this little example I show